# Go x/crypto/ssh -- How to establish ssh connection to private instance over a bastion node

Tags: go, ssh

I want to implement this scenario:
On AWS, I have a VPC, in which it is deployed a public and private subnet. In the public subnet, I have a "bastion" instance, while in private subnet, there is one node running some services(AKA "service instance").
By using *nux ssh command, I can do things like this to connect to the "service instance" from my local laptop:

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i <key> ubuntu@<bastion-ip> nc %h %p" -i <key> ubuntu@<service-instance-ip>
```

I have a Go program, and want to do the following things:

> 1. ssh connect to the "service instance" from "local laptop" over the "bastion"
> 2. use the connection session to run some commands (e.g. "ls -l")
> 3. upload files from "local laptop" to "service instance"

I've tried but not able to implement the same process as doing

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i <key> ubuntu@<bastion-ip> nc %h %p" -i <key> ubuntu@<service-instance-ip>
```

Could anyone help to show me an example?
Thanks!

BTW, I found this:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6223, which means it is definately able to do that, right?

Comment: agent forwarding doesn't really have anything to do with this, especially since you're specifying your private keys on the command line (but you really *should* be using an agent and encrypted keys)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this even more directly with the "x/crypto/ssh" without the `nc` command, since there is a method to dial a connection from the remote host and presents it as a `net.Conn`.

Once you have an `ssh.Client`, you can use the [`Dial`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Client.Dial) method to get a virtual `net.Conn` between you and the final host. You can then turn that into a new `ssh.Conn` with [`ssh.NewClientConn`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#NewClientConn), and create a new `ssh.Client` with [`ssh.NewClient`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#NewClient)

```
// connect to the bastion host
bClient, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", bastionAddr, config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Dial a connection to the service host, from the bastion
conn, err := bClient.Dial("tcp", serviceAddr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

ncc, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(conn, serviceAddr, config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

sClient := ssh.NewClient(ncc, chans, reqs)
// sClient is an ssh client connected to the service host, through the bastion host.
```

Comment: Great thanks! I will try that and give you feedback here.

Comment: Really appreciate that JimB, it is working perfectly!