# How to get BigQuery table expiration date via query / cli / go?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I can't find a way to extract table expiration date that is not via the console (https://console.cloud.google.com/).
We maintain thousands of tables in BQ and we want to enforce the use of table expiration date - so the only way is to collect the data automatically.
is this possible via query/cli/go/python/perl/whatever?

Comment: @TheFool the console is not the bq cli (comman line interface)...

Comment: @TheFool console as "https://console.cloud.google.com/"

Comment: all from program that already collects data on all of the tables @TheFool

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679939/how-do-i-execute-a-command-on-a-remote-machine-in-a-golang-cli

Comment: @TheFool I know I can ssh to the gcp consul. but using the bq cli is simpler as with one command I get the info I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done via querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS`
where option_name='expiration_timestamp'
```

the value will be in the `option_name` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the expiration time from a number of tables in a dataset, you can refer to this documentation [1] (the same query provided by @EldadT), which returns the catalog of tables in a dataset with the expiration time option.

Therefore, if you want to create a script in Python to get the result of this query, you can also check a Client Bigquery Library [2] to run that query and get the expiration time for each table in a dataset.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#example_1_2

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigQuery CLI:

```
bq show mydataset.mytable
```

**Output:**

```
Last modified         Schema         Total Rows   Total Bytes     Expiration      Time Partitioning   Clustered Fields   Labels
----------------- ------------------- ------------ ------------- ----------------- ------------------- ------------------ --------
 16 Aug 10:42:13   |- col_1: integer   7            106           21 Aug 10:42:13
                   |- col_2: string
```