# interactive ssh session in go

Tags: go, ssh, cryptography

ssh interactive session

Hi everyone, I am learning golang for building cli tools and I just thought of replicating something I already have in bash for practice purpose. I want to open ssh interactive terminal using golang. I tried using official golang.org/cryptop/ssh package and could not find a solution for my need. I'm new to go and hence I might not have fully understood the document. I tried this

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    InitServer("152.xx.xx.xx", "ubuntu", "password")
}

const PORT = "22"

func InitServer(server, user, password string) {
    
    sshCommand := exec.Command("ssh", user+"@"+server)

    // Set the standard input, output, and error streams to the current process's streams
    sshCommand.Stdin = os.Stdin
    sshCommand.Stdout = os.Stdout
    sshCommand.Stderr = os.Stderr

    ssh_err := sshCommand.Run()
    if ssh_err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to run SSH command:", ssh_err)
    }

}
```

This works on linux but not when I run main.go in windows. `Failed to run SSH command: exec: "ssh": executable file not found in %PATH%` I also tried to add ssh.exe location to path variable like this

```golang
    sshPath := "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"

    path := os.Getenv("PATH")
    newPath := sshPath + ";" + path

    os.Setenv("PATH", newPath)

    fmt.Println("Updated PATH:", os.Getenv("PATH"))
```

```
Updated PATH: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin
```

Any idea how to handle this, or is there a better way using the official crypto/ssh package ?

Answer (score 0):

For using [crypto/ssh](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) there are several solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679939/how-do-i-execute-a-command-on-a-remote-machine-in-a-golang-cli), and you can ask your problem with that in a separate question to get the right answer.

But for the above case, [you can install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) `openssh` on your Windows system to get the execution of `ssh` command working.

Comment: I have the openssh client installed on windows and it works on the cmd and powershell. ssh -V shows the version. The ssh.exe location is C:\Windows\System32\Openssh\ssh.exe. Still the go is not able to find the executable. In my question I have provided the output of my PATH variable. I found this https://siongui.github.io/2018/03/16/go-check-if-command-exists/#footnote-4 which may lead us somewhere.