# Golang SSH Source Port

Tags: go, ssh, proxy, openssh, netcat

I have a requirement to use a static source port. We will do an IPTables redirect rule based on this source port. So, the static source port is used as an identifier as multiple connections are pending to the same destination port on the server. Think poor man's TCP mux a la `iptables`.

I have followed the Golang examples and cobbled some messy code together. I am not a programmer.

The `ssh.dial` function handles a lot, that becomes apparent once you use `net.dial` along with `ssh.NewClientConn`, `ssh.NewClient` and `ssh.NewSession`.

I see there is no `ProxyCommand` like in OpenSSH config options. I was using:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ncat --source-port %h %p" ...
```

to achieve the requirement in a Bash script.

Additionally, I apologise for a loaded question but `ncat` et al. allow me to reuse the source port immediately.
Whereas Golang SSH leaves a `TIME-WAIT 0 0 192.168.99.53:31337 192.168.99.7:22` for 60 seconds on Arch Linux.
Obviously, subsequent binds to said source port result in an error.

WRT the below code:

- I have omitted the `ExampleHostKeyCheck` function
- I know the `sClient.Listen` is a poor attempt at getting this work
- The remote port forward does NOT appear on the server
- I'm assuming a LOT more code is now required to handle the channels etc.?
- The shell command does work, the file appears in `/tmp/`

```
package main

import (
  "bytes"
  "log"
  "net"
  "os"
  "bufio"
  "strings"
  "path/filepath"

  "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {

  hostKey, err := ExampleHostKeyCheck()
  conf := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "robert",
      Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
      ssh.Password("password"),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
  }

  server, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "centos7.ephemeric.local:22")
  client, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":31337")
  cc, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", client, server)
  //cc, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, server)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s", err)
  }

  defer cc.Close()

  conn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(cc, "", conf)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s", err)
    }
  defer conn.Close()

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906991/go-x-crypto-ssh-how-to-establish-ssh-connection-to-private-instance-over-a-ba
  sClient := ssh.NewClient(conn, chans, reqs)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s", err)
    }
  defer sClient.Close()

  session, err := sClient.NewSession()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s", err)
  }
  defer session.Close()

    sListen, err := sClient.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:31337")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unable to register tcp forward: ", err)
    }
    defer sListen.Close()

  var b bytes.Buffer  // import "bytes"
  session.Stdout = &b // get output
  // You can also pass what gets input to the stdin, allowing you to pipe content from client to server session.Stdin = bytes.NewBufferString("MyInput").
  err = session.Run("echo slobwashere >>/tmp/slobwashere; ls")
}
```

Thank you.